# Custom and browser agent logging in wordpress

Tags: logging

I wanted to log browser agent, screen size, timezone (including current system time). This is my first go at any web server (wordpress is my first install). I wanted to do this without plugins by editing the httpd configuration file.

Can someone please guide me? Also I was reading Apache documentation and there was a warning for write access to logging directory reducing security. What is the best way to have logging and not reduce security of the server?

cheers in advance!

Comment: Although you are using WordPress, this doesn't seem to be a WordPress development question.  If you are new to development and server administration then maybe something like Google Analytics would be an answer.